# NullPointerException getPackageName() on bindService

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a remote service for an android app. I've more or less copied the code from the Android Developers website, retooling it for my purposes. When I get to the bindService step, though, I get a NullPointerException on android.content.Context.getPackageName(). What am I doing wrong?

I've used an in process service with an earlier version of the app, but it wasn't enough for what I wanted from it. The service itself remained the same between the two, other than the necessary changes in code. I've looked at all the results on here, but they were either not related or didn't help me any.

I've tried moving the calls from onCreate to onStart. No difference. onCreate for the BinderActivity never executed. I tried startService instead of bindService, but it gave me the same error. I've checked that this, the intent, and mConnection were all non-null (they are). I know that the service isn't started, but I'm using Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE (which is supposed to start it if it's not). Short of waving a dead chicken over the problem, I'm not sure what else to do here.

My MainActivity:

```java
package com.example.trainchecker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;


import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BinderActivity ba = new BinderActivity();
        ba.BindService();
    }
}
```

This is the BinderActivity, where the magic is supposed to happen. Instead, the error does:

```java
package com.example.trainchecker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Messenger;



public class BinderActivity extends Activity {
    public Messenger ms = null;
    private MainActivity ma;

    class IncomingHandler extends Handler{
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    final Messenger mm = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            Log.d("MCon","Sentinel Online");
            ms = new Messenger(service);
            try {
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null,TCService.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT);
                msg.replyTo = mm;
                ms.send(msg);
            } catch (RemoteException e){   e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.d("MCon","Sentinel Offline");
            try {
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null,2);
                msg.replyTo = mm;
                ms.send(msg);
            } catch (RemoteException e){   e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    };



    public void BindService() {
        bindService(new Intent(this, TCService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }


}
```

And, finally, the service itself. Not much there, but it's mine:

```
package com.example.trainchecker;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;

public class TCService extends Service {

    ArrayList<Messenger> mc = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
        Log.d("TCS", "Binding Now");
        return mm.getBinder();
    }


    static final int MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT = 1;

    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    mc.add(msg.replyTo);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mc.remove(msg.replyTo);
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    final Messenger mm = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
}
```

Here is the error in it's entirety:

```
09-15 11:39:04.518 15448-15448/com.example.trainchecker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.trainchecker, PID: 15448
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trainchecker/com.example.trainchecker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:133)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4468)
        at com.example.trainchecker.BinderActivity.BindService(BinderActivity.java:58)
        at com.example.trainchecker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Hi Crowbarella, welcome to SO. Hmmm what exactly are you trying to do here. Service Binding is to obtain a binding interface so you can potentially call the service directly (like myService.someMethodInMyService() as opposed to having to call `startService()` and pass an Intent.

Comment: You never initialize an Activity yourself in android i.e `BinderActivity ba = new BinderActivity()` . This is a disaster . Activity's instance is automatically created and manages by System itself whenever you start an `Intent` wit an `Activity` . Please read about `Activity` before moving further ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically instantiating an Activity instance doesn't trigger lifecycles therefore your context isn't valid there. Pass it to your BindService() call. Technically speaking your BinderActivity doesn't need to exist and can live in your MainAcitivity or a service.

Comment: Ok, oddly enough that worked. I just pulled the BinderActivity procs into the main activity and executed it from there. I thought I had already tried that at some point, but I guess not. Thanks.